# How to remove elements of a certain class inside a parent element Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span that contains category buttons, and when clicked the subcategory buttons are added within the parent span. The purpose of it is that when the category button is clicked again, if the subcategories have already been populated, it should remove them, like so:

```
$('.catBtns').on('click', function() {
    var catId = parseInt(this.id);
    if ($('#' + catId).parent().find('button').length <= 1) {
        $.each(data.category[catId].subcategory, function(i) {
            $('<button class="subcatBtns" id="'
              + data.category[catId].subcategory[i].subcategoryId + '">'
              + data.category[catId].subcategory[i].subcategoryName.split('<--name-->')[currentLang]
              + '</button>').appendTo($('#' + catId).parent());
            i++;
        });
    } else {
        $('#' + catId).parent().remove('.subcatBtns');
    }
});
```

So far no luck. Why am I unable to remove all elements of class subcatBtns from the parent element of the category button? The jquery API for the remove() method has this example:

```
$( "div" ).remove( ".hello" );
```

Is it because of the parent() method before it? Should I just add a specific Id to the span instead of selecting it through the ID of the child? The HTML is very simple, here:

```
   <nav id="nav">
        <img src="img/resources/logo.png" alt="logo" id="logoMenu">
        <span id="span0" class="catSpan">
            <button class="catBtns" id="0">EN-0</button>
            <button class="subcatBtns" id="000">EN-000</button>
            <button class="subcatBtns" id="001">EN-001</button>
        </span>
        <span id="span1" class="catSpan">
            <button class="catBtns" id="1">EN-1</button>
        </span>
        <span id="span2" class="catSpan">
            <button class="catBtns" id="2">EN-2</button>
        </span>
        <span id="span3" class="catSpan">
            <button class="catBtns" id="3">EN-3</button>
        </span><span id="span4" class="catSpan">
            <button class="catBtns" id="4">EN-4</button>
        </span>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML structure.  We can provide the best jQuery options when we can clearly see the HTML structure you are dealing with.  We have to know where things are relative to each other.

Comment: There don't appear to be any spans in this code...

Comment: Your HTML does not include anything with the `subcatBtns` class...

Comment: The spans are created with the category buttons inside. The subcategory buttons are created on click.

Comment: Why create them when you could just `display:none` them and use the click event to change that object

Comment: @Jhecht - because if I did then on the next click on the category button it would not display the subcategories, since it already has more than one button. As to why not create all the subcategories and hide them, to later display them on click, it's because there are hundreds of subcategories and I'd like to keep it as slim as possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `.remove()` method removes *the elements on which it is called*, optionally filtered by a selector. In the line

```
$('#' + catId).parent().remove('.subcatBtns');
```

You define a set of matched elements which contains only one element (the button container) and then call `.remove()` on this set with the selector `".subcatBtns"`. Since the container does not match the selector, nothing gets removed.

Try, instead:

```
$('#' + catId).parent().find('.subcatBtns').remove();
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks for the explanation, it makes a lot more sense. I need to first select the child elements of class and then remove them.